# AWS shell script to deploy jar file from s3 to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So my current process is to build the project into a jar through mvn,
upload it into S3 bucket through curl via shell script, and now i want to update the lambda function code to point to the newly uploaded file in S3.

Is there a way to do it without CLI and in shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "without CLI", but to do this in a shell script 
you would use the [AWS CLI Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), specifically the command `aws lambda update-function-code` [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html).

Comment: Ah okay thanks, i was a bit confused with aws cli at first. Is there a way to check which s3 code file is being used by a lambda function? Everytime i go into lambda function properties, it just tells me to specify new s3 url, without showing me the one currently in use.

Comment: Not that I know of. Once the function is loaded into Lambda it really isn't tied to S3 anymore. S3 is just used as a staging location. I believe the CLI tool even gives you the option of skipping the S3 upload step.

Comment: how can I do this wih management console? the jar is >10mb and its not getting uploaded. i have created a s3 ucket and uploaded it there. how do i use it in lambda fun?